# React: How to solve: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying fetch data from an API and display the data into list of cards in React with typeScript. Since I am new with React in Typescript, not sure how I can solve this error or am I missing something.

This is the error I get:
Type '{ children: string[]; key: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.

This is the code:

```
    interface Props {
  pokemonItem: PokemonItem;
}

export const PokemonCardList = (props: Props) => {
  const { pokemonItem } = props;
  const {
    id = '',
    name = '',
    weight = '',
    height = '',
    abilities = '',
  } = pokemonItem;

  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = React.useState<PokemonItem[]>([]);
  const [loadItems, setLoadItems] = React.useState(API_URL);

  const getPokemons = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response: any = await fetch(loadItems);
    const data = await response.json();

    setLoadItems(data.next);
    setPokemon(data.results[0].name);
    setLoading(false);
    
    const getEachPokemon = (result: any) => {
      result.forEach(async (element: any) => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https:pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${element.id}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        // // setPokemon((currentArrayList) => [...currentArrayList, data]);
        pokemon.push(data);
      });
    };

    getEachPokemon(data.results);
    await console.log(pokemon);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return getPokemons();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {pokemon &&
        pokemon.map((item, index) => (
          <PokemonCard key={index}>
            {item.name} {item.height} {item.weight} {item.abilities}
          </PokemonCard>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thie pokemonCard component:

```
interface Props {
  pokemonItem: PokemonItem;
}

const PokemonCard = (props: Props) => {
  const { pokemonItem } = props;
  const {
    id = '',
    name = '',
    weight = '',
    height = '',
    abilities = '',
  } = pokemonItem;

  const [imageLoaded, setImageLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  const urlImage = `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${id}.png?raw=true`;

  return (
    <div imageLoaded={imageLoaded}>
      <div
        src={urlImage}
        onLoad={() => setImageLoaded(true)}
      />
      <div>
        Name: {name}
        Height: {height}
        Weight: {weight}
        Abilities: {abilities}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you specify where do you get the error exactly as well as the `PokemonCard` component? It seems that you are passing multiple children to that component without wrapping them in anything, which is not valid JSX.

Comment: Please show the code for the <PokemonCard /> component too

Comment: The error is in the  <PokemonCard key={index}>. The multiple  children was to test, I also tried {...props}, but still kind of confused what would be the right prop to send since it expects a specific props.

Comment: @maten updated the question with new code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your definition of the `PokemonCard` component, you should be passing the `pokemonItem` as follow:

```
<PokemonCard pokemonItem={item} key={item.id} />
```

I have replaced the `key` prop as it is not recommended to use indexes as keys (see [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)), you could use the item's id instead. And you need to update the prop interface for the `PokemonCard` component so that the additional `key` prop doesn't break the validation:

```
interface Props {
  pokemonItem: PokemonItem;
  key: string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped I guess with the type error. Now that I call the cardList component in the App.ts file, how to set the pokemonItem props there?       <PokemonCardList pokemonItem={pokemonItem} />

Comment: Yes, you pass the "item" in the `pokemonItem` prop. If you already have it in a variable, you pass that variable, otherwise you could do something like: `<PokemonCardList pokemonItem={{ id: 'value', name: 'value', weight: 'value' height:: 'value', abilities: 'value' }} />`

Comment: What about the image prop. Do I need to define it as well in the data type interface and pass it as prop in the app.ts file.

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve, for me it seems like the `PokemonCard` component is loading the image on its own and displaying it, so there is no need to pass it around as a prop.

Comment: I think your suggestions helped, but I might have one last question. After fixing the issues with your suggestion, I get an error: TypeError: pokemon.map is not a function - in   {pokemon &&
          pokemon.map((item) => (

Comment: That means that your `pokemon` variable is not an array. You should debug the previous code to see if it is an array or not, and to understand why it isn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238351/discussion-between-waiz-and-houssam).

Comment: This should not be marked the answer, since this does not address the type error.

Answer (score 22):

Use `PropsWithChildren` from `react`:

```
import React, {Component, PropsWithChildren} from "react";

interface OwnProps {
    foo?: BarComponent;
}

// For class component
class MyComponent extend Component<PropsWithChildren<OwnProps>> {
   ...
}

// For FC
const MyFunctionComponent: FC<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = ({
    children,
}) => (...)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this (add type for you component):

`export const PokemonCardList: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import Paper, { PaperProps } from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
    
interface TableEmployeeProps extends PaperProps {
        // your props
}

const TableEmployee: React.FC<TableEmployeeProps> = (props) => {
 return (
      <Paper  {...props}> </Paper>
}
```